# How to use bm font?

Tags: c#, android, fonts, unity-game-engine

I need to use bm font and have 1 fnt file and 2 png files.
The fnt file looks like this..

---

```
info face="³ª´®°íµñ" size=32 bold=0 italic=0 charset="" unicode=1                  stretchH=100 smooth=1 aa=1 padding=0,0,0,0 spacing=1,1 outline=0
common lineHeight=32 base=26 scaleW=1024 scaleH=1024 pages=2 packed=0  alphaChnl=1 redChnl=0 greenChnl=0 blueChnl=0
page id=0 file="nanumgothin_bitmapfont_0.png"
page id=1 file="nanumgothin_bitmapfont_1.png"
chars count=2538
char id=0    x=329   y=1022  width=3     height=1     xoffset=-1       yoffset=31    xadvance=8     page=0  chnl=15
char id=1    x=285   y=1022  width=3     height=1     xoffset=-1    yoffset=31    xadvance=8     page=0  chnl=15
char id=2    x=341   y=1022  width=3     height=1     xoffset=-1    yoffset=31    xadvance=8     page=0  chnl=15

...

...

...

kerning first=89  second=117 amount=-2  
kerning first=89  second=118 amount=-1  
kerning first=89  second=119 amount=-1
```

---

and the png files look like this...

[image]

Looks like the fnt file has some info about each character in the png files.

Can anyone tell me how to use these files? Honestly I don't know how to start with this.
Any comments will be so appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. It would help to know what system you are using...?

Comment: Hi Brian, I am using Unity5., c# and Android platform.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a so called "bitmap font". Unity only supports the use of these on GUI texts and 3D Text objects.

But OnGui() can only use font in the .ttf format

Read this answer on a similar thread in the unity forum:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-4-6-bitmap-font.265209/#post-1853776

> [...] an editor script to generate usable bitmap fonts and based the parsing
>   algorithm on a code snippet I found in the net. I've only tested this
>   with Littera using XML format (.fnt)
>   [...]

There is also a plugin available (paid ~40$) to use bitmap fonts:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/27216